# On clicking link, focus on svg element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I just started working with SVG images and I was wondering if it is possible to create a text link that when on click, it focuses on a specific element.

For example, I have a text that is located on the far left of my screen and a circle element that can only be seen if I scroll to the far right. And when I click on said text, it would then scroll or jump to that element.

I'm still somewhat a beginner at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want the viewport to scroll/jump over to the circle or do you want the text to scroll/jump over to the circle when the text is clicked?

Comment: Viewport to scroll/jump over without the text.

Comment: Have a look into this http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to snap to an element, you can always do the following.

```
<div id="snap-to-me"></div>

<a href="#snap-to-me">SNAP</a>
```

Upon clicking the link, the page will try to find an element with that id, and snap to it.

If you want animated scrolling, I suggest you checkout a library that supports it. jQuery being an obvious, good choice.